# C printf function does not align strings correctly for strings that contain Turkish characters

Tags: c, text, printf, alignment

I have the following code to print some strings on the console in a left aligned format:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s:\n", "Türkçe karakterler ile");
    printf("%-14s: \n", "Onaltılık");
    printf("%-14s: \n", "Onluk");
    printf("%-14s: \n", "İkilik");

    printf("\n%s:\n", "Türkçe karakterler olmadan");
    printf("%-14s: \n", "Onaltilik");
    printf("%-14s: \n", "Onluk");
    printf("%-14s: \n", "Ikilik");
}
```

I compiled this code with both gcc(7.3.0) and clang(6.0.0) on a Ubuntu 18.04 system.

The output is as follows:

```
Türkçe karakterler ile:
Onaltılık  : 
Onluk        : 
İkilik      : 

Türkçe karakterler olmadan:
Onaltilik     : 
Onluk         : 
Ikilik        :
```

As can be seen from the code in the first group of strings there are some Turkish characters such as 'ı' and 'İ'. There is no Turkish characters in the second group of strings.

The output of printf function is not correctly aligned for the strings that contain Turkish characters. The expected output is:

```
Türkçe karakterler ile:
Onaltılık     : 
Onluk         : 
İkilik        : 

Türkçe karakterler olmadan:
Onaltilik     : 
Onluk         : 
Ikilik        :
```

If I compile same code on a Windows system (Windows 7) with gcc (MinGW v5.1.1 inside CodeBlocks 17.2) the output is correct as follows:

```
Türkçe karakterler ile:
Onaltılık     :
Onluk         :
İkilik        :

Türkçe karakterler olmadan:
Onaltilik     :
Onluk         :
Ikilik        :
```

Can anyone help me to figure out what the problem is?

Comment: Have you tried setting `setlocale(LC_ALL,"");` and printing the strings with `puts()` ?

Comment: What does `strlen("Onaltılık)"` return vs. `strlen("Onaltilik)"` on both platforms?

Comment: Maybe try to prefix your strings with `L`? Like this: `L"Turkish characters"`

Comment: @Jabberwocky From the answer below I understood that when there is a string which contains non-ASCII characters as in "Onaltılık" strlen or printf does not return correct result. The expected result from strlen("Onaltılık") is 9, but it returns 11. I think this is because there are two 'ı' characters in the string and it is a non-ASCII (multi-byte) character.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is it's because your editor saved the source using UTF-8, which is a *multi-byte* encoding. The `printf` family of functions only deals with *byte* strings. That means every non-ASCII character will be counted as multiple characters by `printf`.

If it's like that you can work around the problem by printing the string, and then adding padding manually after using the `*` modifier when printing an empty string. The `*` modifier allows you to pass the width as an argument to `printf`.

Something like this:

```
printf("%s%*s: \n", "Onaltılık", 5, "");  // 5 = 14 - 9, where 9 is the number of "characters" in Onaltılık
printf("%s%*s: \n", "Onluk"    , 9, "");  // Dito for Onluk
printf("%s%*s: \n", "İkilik"   , 8, "");  // Dito for İkilik
```

Output:

```
Onaltılık     : 
Onluk         : 
İkilik        :
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While this is not exactly what I'm trying to do, the information is very useful. This explains why I am getting this result. strlen functions does not return the correct length of the string "Onaltılık". I think this also due to the same reason.

I think there should be some solution to this. Other languages (Java, Python, ...) just work with Unicode characters. C should also work with Unicode. I think functions in standard library should be re-implemented to work with Unicode characters.
Thanks anyway...

Comment: @Karşıbalı The "other languages" are really *other* languages. You can't expect two different languages to work the same. Programming languages are kind of like written and spoken languages, no two written and spoken language have the exact same rules and grammar, not even if they are closely related. The same goes for programming languages. In the case of C, it just doesn't have native built-in support for anything but byte-sized characters (or `wchar_t` which still isn't Unicode in any specific way).

Comment: @Karşıbalı There are libraries that you can use to make life with Unicode easier in C, for example [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/). Setting the correct locale *could* help with *some* issues, but far from everything.

Comment: Why do you think same code works correctly on Windows 7?